# Exploring sub-directory from original directory

Tags: c, directory

I'm writing a "virus" for a school project to delete a file from some directory. So, I must traverse the given directory to find the specified file and delete it. However, I can explore the original directory, but when I try to pass it a sub-directory, it says the location doesn't exist. I've tried manually putting in the location, too. Same thing. It's a folder with a folder in it. Nothing else

- StartingFolder
  - SubFolder1
    - SubFolder1_1
      - fileToDelete.txt
- SubFolder2
- SubFolder3

It starts of listing SubFolder1, SubFolder2, and SubFolder3. I concatenate the original location with the new folder and recursively pass the new location. I get no such file or directory.

StartingFolder is a folder at the same directory as the running program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <assert.h>

int checkFolder(char * myPath)
{
DIR           *d;
struct dirent *dir;

int success = 0;
printf("Path: %s\n", myPath);
if ((d = opendir(myPath)) != NULL)
{

   while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
  {

     char * seperator = "\\";
     char * pathFound = dir->d_name;   
     char * tempPath = "";         

     tempPath = malloc(sizeof(tempPath));
     strcpy(tempPath, myPath);

     strcat(tempPath, seperator);
     strcat(tempPath, pathFound);
      //printf("Files in Path: %s\n",tempPath);

      if(strstr(tempPath, ".txt"))
      {
         success = 1;
      }
      else if(!strchr(tempPath, '.'))
      {     
         checkFolder(tempPath);
      }



  }

  closedir(d);
}
 else
  {
     perror("opendir() error");
 }

return success;
}

 int main(void)
 {

char * myPath;
int success;
myPath = malloc(sizeof(myPath));
myPath = "StartingFolder";
success = checkFolder(myPath);
printf("%d\n",success);

return(0);

}
```

Comment: The system call is not `openfolder` because the objects you are working with are not called "folders".  They are called "directories".

Comment: Your `malloc` is allocating only 4 or 8 bytes.  Try something much bigger like `malloc(1024)`.

Comment: Also check out http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Walk_a_directory/Recursively#C for an example.

Comment: @William Pursell Folders and directories are essentially the same thing. It just depends on the situation. GUI typically say folders while cmd lines/programs tend to say directories. I understand this and I don't use openfolder in my program anywhere. Could you clarify?

Comment: "folder" is a word invented by the marketing department.  It has no place in a technical discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char * seperator = "\\";
```

should be

```
char * seperator = "/";
```

combine that with Jonathan Leffler's answer and you have a solid "virus" to delete a file from a directory.

Answer (score 1):

#### Original answer

The usual cause of this trouble is that you do not:

- Change directory as you progress, *or*
- Build the complete path properly.

The values returned by `readdir()` are the simple file names.  If it is in a sub-sub-directory, you have to prefix the file name with the sub-directory and sub-sub-directory names.  Either of the options given will work.  However, `chdir()` is more fraught than building the path — even ignoring symbolic links.

#### *Commentary*

While the 'usual cause' is often the trouble, it is not the primary cause of trouble in this program.

#### Analysis

The memory allocation in the program is unnecessarily complex, and faulty as well.  Here is a variant version of your code, formatted more or less according to my prejudices (I haven't tweaked everything in `uncrustify` to suit me yet), that works on my Mac.  It would probably (but not definitively) work on Windows too — it certainly should work if you replace the `"/"` with `"\\"` as in the original code.

I've removed superfluous headers and variables.

Your code only works sanely when directory names do not contain `.` in their name and files do contain a `.` in the name.  Your code will recognize the file `horrid.txt-or-binary` because it contains the string `.txt`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

static int checkFolder(char *myPath)
{
    DIR           *d;
    struct dirent *dir;

    int success = 0;
    printf("Path: %s\n", myPath);
    if ((d = opendir(myPath)) != NULL)
    {
        while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
        {
            char *separator = "/";
            char *pathFound = dir->d_name;
            char  tempPath[1024];

            strcpy(tempPath, myPath);
            strcat(tempPath, separator);
            strcat(tempPath, pathFound);
            printf("Files in Path: %s\n", tempPath);

            if (strstr(tempPath, ".txt"))
            {
                success = 1;
                printf("Found: %s\n", tempPath);
            }
            else if (strchr(tempPath, '.') == 0)
            {
                checkFolder(tempPath);
            }
        }

        closedir(d);
    }
    else
    {
        perror("opendir() error");
    }

    return success;
}

int main(void)
{
    char myPath[] = "StartingFolder";
    int success = checkFolder(myPath);
    printf("%d\n", success);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Ok, so since I'm on the school's network, I need to figure out what the network location is of SubFolder1? because anything outside the root dir requires the full path name?

Comment: You don't necessarily need the full path name.  You just need to make sure you prefix the name returned by `readdir()` with the appropriate (relative, not absolute) path.

Comment: Ok, sounds like I need to get that from my teacher or something b/c I have no idea what the prefix path is to these folders. On my machine it's H:/ but it also has some network location. I'm lost as to what the "correct" location is supposed to be. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a comment rather than an answer, but comments are hard to edit.

The following is odd:

```
  char * myPath;
  int success;
  myPath = malloc(sizeof(myPath));
  myPath = "StartingFolder";
```

The `malloc` is totally pointless here, and is a memory leak.  You allocate enough space for a pointer, then you immediately discard that memory without every freeing it.  Just omit the `malloc`.  Also, add some flexibility by using `argv[1]` instead of a fixed string.

Comment: leftover code from doing something else. Thanks for catching it. I'm still learning the ins and outs of C memory usage so I tend to over-look and/or misuse malloc/free sometimes. I don't need to make the location dynamic for this project. I would have used argv[1] otherwise.